# Polymorphism with abstract class (C++)

Tags: c++

this is my code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstring>  

using namespace std;
//abstract class
class GMatrix {
    string name;
    int nrows;
    int ncols;
public:
    GMatrix(const string & n, int nr, int nc);
     virtual GMatrix& add(const GMatrix&)= 0;
};

class RMatrix : public GMatrix {
    vector<int>numbers;
public:
    RMatrix(const string & n, int nr, int nc, vector<int> nums);
    RMatrix& add(const RMatrix&);
};

GMatrix::GMatrix(const string& n, int nr, int nc){
    name=n;
    nrows=nr;
    ncols=nc;
}

RMatrix::RMatrix(const string & n,int nr, int nc, vector<int> nums):GMatrix(n,nr,nc){
    numbers=numbers;   
}

RMatrix& RMatrix::add(const RMatrix& x){
    for(int i =0; i = numbers.size(); i++){
        numbers.at(i)+=x.numbers.at(i);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    vector<int> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < 16 ; i++){
        n.push_back(i);
    }

    RMatrix a("a",4,4,n);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, my program consists of two classes, one (parent class) is abstract so methods here have no functionality and one children class. My problem is that this code canot be build. I try to create object a as RMatrix object but compiler shows this errors which i dont understand:

```
main.cpp:48:13: error: cannot declare variable ‘a’ to be of abstract type ‘RMatrix’
main.cpp:18:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘RMatrix’:
main.cpp:15:23: note:   virtual GMatrix& GMatrix::add(const GMatrix&)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `RMatrix`'s `add` member function does not match the signature of the pure virtual `add` function in `GMatrix`.

What you need is

```
GMatrix & RMatrix::add(const GMatrix &)
```

but what you have is

```
RMatrix & RMatrix::add(const RMatrix &)
```

The function you have does not match the signature conceptually (as in, this paragraph is about OOP in general, not just C++) because while all `RMatrix`s are `GMatrix`s, not all `GMatrix`s are `RMatrix`s. This means that if somebody does something like create a class `FooMatrix` that extends `GMatrix`, then creates instances of `FooMatrix` and `RMatrix` and uses `GMatrix` references to access them, they will not be able to use the `RMatrix& RMatrix::add(const RMatrix&)` method to add the two matrices, even though `GMatrix` specifies that the `add` method that concrete subclasses implement must be able to be called using **any** `GMatrix`.

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem because const GMatrix has no member numbers

Comment: @privatedatapublicchannel2 It doesn't immediately result in working code, but I believe it gives the asker enough information to fix their code and avoid the issue in the future.

Comment: @Eric: Except the code cannot be fixed, there is a core design issue in that the inheritance relationship does not follow LSP

Answer (score 3):

You are breaking the Liskov's substitution principle. Your derived type cannot be used in place of the base, since you can *add* any `GMatrix` to the base, but only `RMatrix` to the derived type.

The `add` member function in the derived type is not an *override* of the member function by the same name in the base type.

Answer (score 1):

`RMatrix` is also an abstract class because you haven't implemented the

```
virtual GMatrix& add(const GMatrix&)= 0;
```

method. In `RMatrix`, this method is still pure virtual. This is why you cannot construct an `RMatrix` object.

Answer (score 1):

The method

```
RMatrix& RMatrix::add(const RMatrix&);
```

doesn't override

```
virtual GMatrix& GMatrix::add(const GMatrix&)= 0;
```

so code fails because `GMatrix::add` is pure virtual. You can add {} to solve the issue (by the way at the moment it looks like you don't need `GMatrix::add` at all...):

```
class GMatrix {
    string name;
    int nrows;
    int ncols;
public:
    GMatrix(const string & n, int nr, int nc);
     virtual GMatrix& add(const GMatrix&){}
};

class RMatrix : public GMatrix {
    vector<int>numbers;
public:
    RMatrix(const string & n, int nr, int nc, vector<int> nums);
    RMatrix& add(const RMatrix&);
};
```

http://ideone.com/SLObkC

Comment: Not good. Pure virtual functions are used to force the developer to override them. If you remove the pure virtual function, when you have something like this:
`GMatrix *matrix = new RMatrix;  matrix->add(other);` it won't do anything.